# ejabberd mod_archive_odbc internal-server-error

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I am trying to retrieve a collection of a messages from ejabberd server with Strophe. I use query:

```
$iq({type: 'get'}).c('retrieve', {xmlns: 'http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#ns', with:'pivo@localhost/local',  start: '2012-10-28T17:38:00.000000Z'}).c('set', {xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'}).c('max').t('100');
```

and this will generate following XMPP packet for me:

```
<iq type='get' xmlns='jabber:client'>
    <retrieve xmlns='http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#ns' with='pivo@localhost/local' start='2012-10-28T17:38:00.000000Z'>
        <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
            <max>100</max>
        </set>
    </retrieve>
</iq>
```

But problem is that server dont't reply with success, he returns me internal-server-error.

If i look into Postgres logs i can find following error:

```
**ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "0000-01-01 00:00:00" at character 68**
```

I am using ejabberd 2.1.10, pgsql 9.1.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2):

at first you must check that this collection is exist or not.
you can do this with :

```
<iq type='get' id='123456'>
  <list xmlns='http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#ns'
        with='jabbar@localhost'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>30</max>/*max number of collection that you want to retrieve*/ 
    </set>
  </list>
</iq>
```

response from ejabberd:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client'
    from='root@localhost'
    to='root@localhost/24975890851351278205927376'
    id='123456'
    type='result'>
<list xmlns='http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#ns'>
<chat with='jabbar@localhost/2021512663135182487476431'
      start='2012-10-24T13:45:17.000000Z'/>
<chat with='jabbar@localhost/9286394041351135710472543'
      start='2012-10-25T20:09:13.000000Z'/>
<chat with='jabbar@localhost/9286394041351135710472543'
      start='2012-10-25T21:22:13.000000Z'/>/****** I will retrieve this *****/
<chat with='jabbar@localhost/9286394041351135710472543'
      start='2012-10-25T22:05:13.000000Z'/>
<chat with='jabbar@localhost'
      start='2012-10-25T23:03:14.000000Z'/>
<chat with='jabbar@localhost'
      start='2012-10-25T23:35:37.000000Z'/>
<set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
<first index='0'>
63518305517@1
</first>
<last>
63518427337@15
</last>
<changed>
2012-10-25T23:37:21.000000Z
</changed>
<count>
6
</count>
</set>
</list>
</iq>
```

now for retrieving message from a collection you must input exactly "start" and "with" in request stanza:

```
<iq type='get' id='433534536'>
  <retrieve xmlns='http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#ns'
            with='jabbar@localhost/9286394041351135710472543'
            start='2012-10-25T21:22:13.000000Z'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>100</max>
    </set>
  </retrieve>
</iq>
```

response:

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client'
    from='root@localhost'
    to='root@localhost/24975890851351278205927376'
    id='433534536'
    type='result'>
<chat with='jabbar@localhost/9286394041351135710472543'
      start='2012-10-25T21:22:13.000000Z'>
<from secs='0'>
<body>
dddddddddd
</body>
</from>
<from secs='1'>
<body>
dddddddd
</body>
</from>
<set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
<first index='0'>
63518419333@103
</first>
<last>
63518419334@105
</last>
<changed>
2012-10-25T21:22:14.000000Z
</changed>
<count>
2
</count>
</set>
</chat>
</iq>
```

Comment: I was trying exactly the same thing, but I got an error. If i query collection which doesn't exists, he return me "item-not-found", but if I query correct collection he returns me an error :( . What mod you use on ejabberd server side?

Comment: i use mod_archive_odbc with mysql external database.your database schema is correct?.look at tables of ejabberd and be sure that collections and time you wanna retrieve(utc) are exist.

Comment: I will make REST service for getting messages for some collection, it seems to mod_archive_odbc with pgsql 9.1 have some bug with UTC time. Unfortunately mod_archive_odbc for this version of ejabberd is depricated, and the author develops mod for new ejabberd